# Why does the word "inadvertently" mean "not knowingly"?

Tags: adverbs, roots

The root is *advertently*. That means “knowingly”. Fair enough. The root of *advertently* is *advertent*. That means “attention”. Hmmm … quite close. The root of *advertent* is *advert*, which means “advertising”. Okay, I am missing something here. What does *advertising* have to do with *advertently*? Are these the real root words?

Comment: The first stop for etymology is [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com).

Comment: I like your efforts and "analysis". Can you include the sources of your information?

Comment: The meaning of a word is not necessarily the same as the combination of the meanings of its parts. Also, the meaning of a word is not necessarily the same meaning as wha it used to be. Usually they are nearby which is the case here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you think *inadvertently* means unknowingly? It doesn’t. It means, in the OED’s definition, ‘without due attention or thought; inattentively, heedlessly, carelessly; hence, unintentionally.’

The root meaning of words derived from Latin *advertere* is ‘turn or direct towards’. *Advertent* means ‘intentional, deliberate; conscious’, because in being advertent we pay attention to something, that is, we turn our minds towards it. An *advertisement* turns our direction towards the product or service that the advertiser is promoting.

Comment: That's really great!